# Cucumber can't find step definitions during running from JAR using TestNG

Tags: jar, cucumber, testng

I am trying to execute my project with Maven+Cucumber+TestNG+Selenide from the JAR file, but without success.

I have the main class as start point of the project. This is "main" method in the "src/main/java/ru/mysite/starters/EntryPoint.java":

```
    public class EntryPoint {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Some code for loading settings
    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    testNG.setTestClasses(new Class[] { Dev_RunTest_Electron.class, Dev_RunTest_Web.class });
    testNG.run();
    }
```

I have ttwo runner classes like following:

```
    @CucumberOptions(publish = false,
                     features = "src/main/resources/features/",
                     plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report.html", "json:target/cucumber.json", "testng:target/cucumberTestNG.xml"},
                     glue = {"classpath:ru.mysite.cucumber"},
                     tags = "@Dev and @Web")
    public class Dev_RunTest_Web extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
        @Override
        @DataProvider(parallel = true)
        public Object[][] scenarios() {
            return super.scenarios();
        }
    }
```

If I try to execute this code from IntellijIDEA using "Run" or "Debug" for "EntryPoint" class, all my tests executes normally.

If I try to run my JAR file from the root directory of the project, I receiving a lot of errors (number of errors equals to number of tests):
***io.cucumber.testng.UndefinedStepException: The step 'система помещает в переменную "${идентификатор владельца}" новый идентификатор' and 36 other step(s) are undefined.
You can implement these steps using the snippet(s) below:***

However, I have all steps definitions.

There is a part of my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <finalName>mysite-executable</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <mainClass>
                                            ru.mysite.starters.EntryPoint
                                        </mainClass>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>
                                <descriptorRefs>
                                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                </descriptorRefs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
           </plugins>
</build>
```

So, my misunderstanding is why I can run "EntryPoint" class from IntellijIdea, but can't do the same from the JAR?

JAR have 36Mb size - looks like full package. In the JAR file I can see folders structure like "ru\mysite\cucumber\glue" and subfolders like "common", "api" etc. In those subfolders I have classes with steps (for example, "Confirmations_Sites.class").
I am trying to execute JAR using following command:

```
java -jar mysite-executable-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Cucumber scans the classpath for glue code. Maybe it doesn't work inside a jar with dependencies. Did you attach a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: I did not. Will try this manual tomorrow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-jar.html